# creating folders and permissions in linux

Tags: php, chmod, mkdir

I wanted to create a folder and set its permission.
It was working fine with windows, but when I shifted to linux,
it had permission problems.

```
//Make new directory    
$directory = dirname($this->fileName);
if(!is_dir($directory)) {
  if (!mkdir($directory, 0777, true))
    die('Failed to create folders...');
} else {
  die('ah ok...');
}
```

For this to work, I have to set the folder permission manually to `777`.
Then after that the application can run successfully.

Then I delete the existing folder again to test it, cannot create again because
permission denied, it fails to create folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check your [`umask()`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) and set it to `0`. If your umask is `0022` for example, your newly created directory will have permission 0755 instead of 0777 when you create it.